# Target number at the start of a string with CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, divi

I am trying to target the size of a number at the start of a word.

For example - I have the brand 4ever and want to resize the '4' to be the same size as the trailing text 'eva'

Is there a way to do this in CSS or do I need Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: just to add that the word isn't always first in the sentence. I have tried using <span> to target it but will not work.

Answer (score 1):

you can try it with ::first-letter.

Check docs here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp

```
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 200%;
  color: #8A2BE2;
}
```

Comment: I used the 'dropcap' function and styled that in CSS to cover instances where the 4ever is the first word of a sentence but this does not work if the word is mid-sentence.

.et-dropcap {
    
    font-size: 14px;
 margin-right: -.4px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-family: baijam-regular;
 font-weight: 500;
}